# Write a list's content on an email

Tags: properties, jakarta-mail

I use a file properties where I define the body message of my email. For example, I have this property:

```
mail.model.message=My name is ${name}.
```

Where `${name}` is a variable.

But what if I have a list of names? how can I write a loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a loop it's:

```
[#list listName]${name}[/#list]
```